# Clearing fieldGroup's fields when hidden

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I need to clear all fields when they are hidden by a `hideExpression`, right now i have some code that adds a watcher to fields, and clearing them if they are hidden.

Problem is that this doesnt work for `hideExpression`'s used on fields with `fieldGroup`'s, since its apearently not allowed to add watcher to that type.

My example might explaine the issue better:
http://jsbin.com/fodijeziyu/1/edit?js,output

If you fill in the values, and click the hide checkbox, they should clear the model/view on the fields that gets hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Generally on angular I would think different ways of doing things so that I won't be using watchers. It decreases performance a lot (and yes that sometimes might mean to use jQuery for it).

Now for angular-formly a way of doing what you want would be to use a function for `hideExpression` and achieve what you want.

Here is a [working example](https://jsbin.com/moravuw/edit?js,console,output).

Also read this [link](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions#watcher) on the official angular-formly documentation.

Comment: In this example with a couple of input fields this may be a fine way, but the problem is that i need this for a huge and complex form. so i cant be setting that kind of hideExpression everywhere. i need something more generic

Answer (score 1):

There's an example on the website for this: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/very-advanced/remove-property-on-hide

Comment: If i add a fieldGroup to that example, it throws an `"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"` , can you give an example with a fieldGroup?

Comment: [This](https://jsbin.com/nazamo/edit?js,console,output) is as far as I got before I realized that `fieldGroup` doesn't support `watcher`... PRs accepted :-) You'd need to adjust [this line](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/src/directives/formly-form.js#L270-L272) and add `watcher` to [this](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/src/providers/formlyApiCheck.js#L175-L190) (probably by extracting [this](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/src/providers/formlyApiCheck.js#L116-L121) to a variable and reusing it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the watch with the true flag, in conjunction with your hideExpression:

```
$scope.$watch('someMiscForm', function() {
    console.log('The model has changed!');
}, true);
```

Then alter/reset the fields you are interested in.

Comment: As i see it, that wont work. i would not trigger the watcher when the fieldGroup gets hidden.